# update dynamic object in redux using spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to update an object in redux using spread operator but I am not being able to.
Initial state is an empty object because *category* is received dynamically from api call.
*pages* and *data* are both objects which i want to update using spread operator (or whatever works best)

```
 state = {
      [category]: {
        pages: {
          key: value(array)
        },
        data: {
          key: value(array)
        }
      }
    }
```

At my reducer I try to update it like this

```
 return {
        ...state,
        [category]: {
          ...state[category],
          pages: { ...state[category].pages, pages },
          data: { ...state[category].data, doctors },
          total: total,
        },
      };
```

but i get "error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'pages' of undefined"

What am I doing wrong and how can I update them correctly?

Comment: it seems like you are trying to update reducer before getting API data or you don't or pages does not exists in your response

Comment: pages do exist in the response because if i just set pages:pages, it will get the values, but it overwrites it and i want to update it with previous results

Comment: then category does not exists in the state (state[category])that you are searching at first time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `state.category` is undefined when you fetch this category for the first time. You can fix it like that:

```js
return {
  ...state,
  [category]: state.category
    ? {
        ...state[category],
        pages: { ...state[category].pages, pages },
        data: { ...state[category].data, doctors },
        total: total,
      }
    : {
        pages,
        data: doctors,
        total,
      },
};
```

Comment: thank you very much. it worked. just had to change   [category]: state[category] ? { ...

Comment: I'm glad that helped.